# Find and Replace for an Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, replace

Would anyone have any idea how to make a Find and Replace thing where when you can just click next it will bring you to the next found item?

**Edit:**

For an Textarea. I want a Javascript code that can add a Find and Replace to Textarea. I don't wanna just use.

search()

or Replace().

At the Moment im trying this:

```
function allIndexes() {
var indices = new Array();
var index = 0;
var i = 0;
while(index = $('#text').val().indexOf($('#search').val(), index) > 0) {
indices[i] = index;
i++;
}
return indices;
}
```

But that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I updated my earlier answer and finished the search and replace functionality based on the direction my earlier post outlined. I tested this in Chrome 14, IE8 and Firefox 3.6.

**Find**: will select the next instance of the searchterm.

**Find/Replace**: will replace the next occurrence of the search string and select the replacement

**Replace All:** will replace all occurences and select the piece of text that has been replaced last

Hope this is now, what you were looking for. You should definitely be able to go from here and style this or make a proper class out of this...

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<textarea id="txtArea" style="width: 300px; height:100px">
    This is a test. A test, i say. The word TEST is mentioned three times.
</textarea>

<p>
    <label for="termSearch">Search</label>
    <input type="text" id="termSearch" name="termSearch" value="test" /><br/>
    <label for="termReplace">Replace</label>
    <input type="text" id="termReplace" name="termReplace" value="solution" /><br/>
    <label for="caseSensitive">Case Sensitive</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="caseSensitive" id="caseSensitive" /><br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="SAR.find(); return false;" id="find">FIND</a><br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="SAR.findAndReplace(); return false;" id="findAndReplace">FIND/REPLACE</a><br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="SAR.replaceAll(); return false;" id="replaceAll">REPLACE ALL</a><br/>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var SAR = {};

    SAR.find = function(){
        // collect variables
        var txt = $("#txtArea").val();
        var strSearchTerm = $("#termSearch").val();
        var isCaseSensitive = ($("#caseSensitive").attr('checked') == 'checked') ? true : false;

        // make text lowercase if search is supposed to be case insensitive
        if(isCaseSensitive == false){
            txt = txt.toLowerCase();
            strSearchTerm = strSearchTerm.toLowerCase();
        }

        // find next index of searchterm, starting from current cursor position
        var cursorPos = ($("#txtArea").getCursorPosEnd());
        var termPos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm, cursorPos);

        // if found, select it
        if(termPos != -1){
            $("#txtArea").selectRange(termPos, termPos+strSearchTerm.length);
        }else{
            // not found from cursor pos, so start from beginning
            termPos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm);
            if(termPos != -1){
                $("#txtArea").selectRange(termPos, termPos+strSearchTerm.length);
            }else{
                alert("not found");
            }
        }
    };

    SAR.findAndReplace = function(){
        // collect variables
        var origTxt = $("#txtArea").val(); // needed for text replacement
        var txt = $("#txtArea").val(); // duplicate needed for case insensitive search
        var strSearchTerm = $("#termSearch").val();
        var strReplaceWith = $("#termReplace").val();
        var isCaseSensitive = ($("#caseSensitive").attr('checked') == 'checked') ? true : false;
        var termPos;

        // make text lowercase if search is supposed to be case insensitive
        if(isCaseSensitive == false){
            txt = txt.toLowerCase();
            strSearchTerm = strSearchTerm.toLowerCase();
        }

        // find next index of searchterm, starting from current cursor position
        var cursorPos = ($("#txtArea").getCursorPosEnd());
        var termPos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm, cursorPos);
        var newText = '';

        // if found, replace it, then select it
        if(termPos != -1){
            newText = origTxt.substring(0, termPos) + strReplaceWith + origTxt.substring(termPos+strSearchTerm.length, origTxt.length)
            $("#txtArea").val(newText);
            $("#txtArea").selectRange(termPos, termPos+strReplaceWith.length);
        }else{
            // not found from cursor pos, so start from beginning
            termPos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm);
            if(termPos != -1){
                newText = origTxt.substring(0, termPos) + strReplaceWith + origTxt.substring(termPos+strSearchTerm.length, origTxt.length)
                $("#txtArea").val(newText);
                $("#txtArea").selectRange(termPos, termPos+strReplaceWith.length);
            }else{
                alert("not found");
            }
        }
    };

    SAR.replaceAll = function(){
        // collect variables
        var origTxt = $("#txtArea").val(); // needed for text replacement
        var txt = $("#txtArea").val(); // duplicate needed for case insensitive search
        var strSearchTerm = $("#termSearch").val();
        var strReplaceWith = $("#termReplace").val();
        var isCaseSensitive = ($("#caseSensitive").attr('checked') == 'checked') ? true : false;

        // make text lowercase if search is supposed to be case insensitive
        if(isCaseSensitive == false){
            txt = txt.toLowerCase();
            strSearchTerm = strSearchTerm.toLowerCase();
        }

        // find all occurances of search string
        var matches = [];
        var pos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm);
        while(pos > -1) {
            matches.push(pos);
            pos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm, pos+1);
        }

        for (var match in matches){
            SAR.findAndReplace();
        }
    };


    /* TWO UTILITY FUNCTIONS YOU WILL NEED */
    $.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if(this.setSelectionRange) {
                this.focus();
                this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
            } else if(this.createTextRange) {
                var range = this.createTextRange();
                range.collapse(true);
                range.moveEnd('character', end);
                range.moveStart('character', start);
                range.select();
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.getCursorPosEnd = function() {
        var pos = 0;
        var input = this.get(0);
        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {
            input.focus();
            var sel = document.selection.createRange();
            pos = sel.text.length;
        }
        // Firefox support
        else if (input.selectionStart || input.selectionStart == '0')
            pos = input.selectionEnd;
        return pos;
    };  
</script>
```

Comment: Isn;t there an search box for this? I don't get this.

Comment: Also this is not what I was looking for but that's for the try. :) You get best answer because of your great looking code. And you afford of making it.

Comment: I updated my earlier, rough direction and this is now a fully functioning example of search and replace functionality on a textarea through javascript. Let me know if this is more useful.

Comment: Hi @Jens Fischer, I know this is an old post, but I ask in case you see this: Can you add a save function to this script, I mean something in the way of <a href="#" onclick="SAR.save(); return false;" id="save">Save changes</a>, thanks and I hope you see this..

Answer (score 1):

This answer is those looking for a **more complete and polished** version of [Jens Fischer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781099/find-and-replace-for-an-textarea/7781395#7781395) with **added functionalities** such as find previous, find next, find and replace using regular expression, undo and redo.

Here is the link to the GitHub project: https://github.com/AlienKevin/SmartTextarea

Answer (score 0):

javascript---------------------------------

```
        function dog(id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
        function find()
        {
            var a=dog("txtf").value;
            var b=dog("ta").value;
            var c="";
            for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            {
                var d=b.substr(i,a.length)
                if (d.indexOf(a) > -1)          
                    c=c +" " + (d.indexOf(a)+i);
            }
            if (c!="")
            {
                alert(c);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("not find");
            }
        }
        function replace()
        {
            var a=dog("txtf").value;
            var b=dog("ta").value;
            var c="";
            for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            {
                var d=b.substr(i,a.length)
                if (d.indexOf(a) > -1)      
                {
                    c=c + dog("txtr").value;
                    i=i+a.length-1;
                }
                else
                    c=c + b.charAt(i);
            }
            dog("ta").value=c;
        }
```

html ------------------------------------------------

```
    <input type="text" id="txtf" value="this" style="width:427px"/>
    <input type="button" value="Find" style="width:70px" onclick="find()" /> </br>
    <input type="text" id="txtr" value="it" style="width:427px"/>

    <input type="button" value="Replace" style="width:70px" onclick="replace()"/> </br>
    <textarea id="ta" style="width:500px;height:500px">
```

this is a text area for test find & replace functions
this is a project for find & replace in html programing language

Answer (score 0):

//there is some mistake in the scrolling so below is the correction working fine in chrome.

```
 //Complete code
```

var SAR = {};

```
            SAR.find = function () {
                debugger;
                var parola_cercata = $("#text_box_1").val(); // the searched word
                // make text lowercase if search is supposed to be case insensitive
                var txt = $('#remarks').val().toLowerCase();
                parola_cercata = parola_cercata.toLowerCase();

                var posi = jQuery('#remarks').getCursorPosEnd(); // take the position of the word in the text

                var termPos = txt.indexOf(parola_cercata, posi);

                if (termPos !== -1) {
                    debugger;
                    var target = document.getElementById("remarks");
                    var parola_cercata2 = $("#text_box_1").val();
                    // select the textarea and the word
                    if (target.setSelectionRange) {

                        if ('selectionStart' in target) {
                            target.selectionStart = termPos;
                            target.selectionEnd = termPos;
                            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = target.value.indexOf(parola_cercata2);
                            target.blur();
                            target.focus();
                            target.setSelectionRange(termPos, termPos + parola_cercata.length);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var r = target.createTextRange();
                        r.collapse(true);
                        r.moveEnd('character', termPos + parola_cercata);
                        r.moveStart('character', termPos);
                        r.select();
                    }
                } else {
                    // not found from cursor pos, so start from beginning
                    termPos = txt.indexOf(parola_cercata);
                    if (termPos !== -1) {
                        var target = document.getElementById("remarks");
                        var parola_cercata2 = $("#text_box_1").val();
                        // select the textarea and the word
                        if (target.setSelectionRange) {

                            if ('selectionStart' in target) {
                                target.selectionStart = termPos;
                                target.selectionEnd = termPos;
                                this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = target.value.indexOf(parola_cercata2);
                                target.blur();
                                target.focus();
                                target.setSelectionRange(termPos, termPos + parola_cercata.length);
                            }
                        } else {
                            var r = target.createTextRange();
                            r.collapse(true);
                            r.moveEnd('character', termPos + parola_cercata);
                            r.moveStart('character', termPos);
                            r.select();
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("not found");
                    }
                }
            };


            $.fn.getCursorPosEnd = function () {
                var pos = 0;
                var input = this.get(0);
                // IE Support
                if (document.selection) {
                    input.focus();
                    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
                    pos = sel.text.length;
                }
                // Firefox support
                else if (input.selectionStart || input.selectionStart === '0')
                    pos = input.selectionEnd;
                return pos;
            };
        </script>
```