# java function to save textarea content retrieved from a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea that retrieves the text from a file using php

```
<textarea id="txtArea" rows="26"><?php include_once( $theFile ); ?></textarea>
```

and I have found a java code that allows me to search and replace text over the retrieved file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781395/443381

But what this code does not include is the saving function to save the changes I've done to the same file, I have tried to add the function myself with no success, so is anybody that could help me to achieve this, thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() for this. The first would replace your current include_once. The include_once() will run any PHP code inside the file, which means you'd be letting people control PHP code on your server which is a really really bad security problem. You also want to look into XSS attacks and you'd want to use something like htmlentities() around the file_get_contents() part to protect against that. And if $theFile happens to be user-entered data, you are opening yet another security hole.

Comment: Javascript != java...removed tag

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have tried file_get_contents() but this renders no content on the textarea, so what else I could try, I mean I have tried with : <textarea id="txtArea" rows="26"><?php file_get_contents( $theFile ); ?></textarea>

Comment: Sorry @Steve Siebert those were the suggested tags

Comment: Thanks again @DampeS8N I could finally figure out how to display the file in the way you suggested: <?php $tokfile=$_POST['tokfile'];
$theFile = './tokfiles/'.$tokfile;
$todisplay = file_get_contents( $theFile );
?><textarea id="txtArea" rows="26"><?php echo $todisplay; ?></textarea>

Comment: I strongly advise you use a white-list of files and pick from that list rather than allowing the user to input any input the way you are right now. While prefixing the file with a specific folder is a deterrent, it probably isn't perfect. I also strongly advise you change`<?php echo $todisplay; ?>` to `<?php echo htmlentities($todisplay); ?>` to protect against XSS attacks. Consider if someone changed the file to be this text `</textarea><script> window.location = 'www.badsite.com' </script><textarea>`

Comment: As you could've noticed I'm not an expert, I'm following your advices, now is with htmlentities, Well I better explain what this all thing does. Upload script only accepts pdf, txt, doc, docx, odt, rtf and convert them into a text file which is then tokenized (a word per line) and that is presented to the user with <?php echo htmlentities($todisplay); ?> for him to check if tokenization is good, my idea was to give ability to edit and save at web, but I can't get it to work yet, so in the meantime the user has to download the date_name.tok file and correct it localy to then upload it again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want, something I've made before... I can save and load drafts. For example I can load text into a textarea from a file, edit it, then save the edited version back into the file, and repeat. Is that right? If so, here's the full code for it, literally, all the work done for you:

http://pastebin.com/kZXhQzPn

Comment: Can I do this? <?php $tokfile=$_POST['tokfile'];
if($_GET['draft']==1){
$draft=1;
$filepath = 'tokfiles/'.$tokfile;
$msg = file_get_contents($filepath);
}
?>
for a different file, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: The thing is that the php that displays the file is getting the filename from a previous php where it was uploaded

Comment: If you want to paste bin your entire code and put the link in a comment here and tell me the exact problem, I can attempt to fix it here in another comment. Otherwise, indeed, my file in that example is static. But it was dynamic before I edited it. I had filepath = $username . ".dat" (remembering to add the file extension to the current user's name so every user has their own draft file).

Comment: Well, down in the .js where you see SAR.find etc. Add your SAR.save. And add your SAR.Save() a href link. Try to copy a working function first. Then make tweaks to it accordingly. The JS can set the value where you have 'echo $todisplay,' which should be the case, unless you have PHP above the head tag that loads when the page loads and sets todisplay? Otherwise, todisplay is not possibly going to have a value as is, I don't think. Sorry to not simply do the code for you. It's a bit lengthy and I'm not as good with jQuery.