# Find and select text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I need to find and select text in the textarea in my electron app. I found a pretty good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781099/find-and-replace-for-an-textarea/7781395#7781395).

But when searching the contents are not scrolls. I tried to solve a problem like this:

`document.getElementById('editor').setSelectionRange(cursorPos,cursorPos);`

But it does not work as we would like:

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: create an example, like a jsfiddle for us to look at.

Comment: It's weird, but it works in the jsfiddle but in my electron app its doesent work O_o

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/4buos6L9/2/)

Comment: I figured..Content is scrolling in the firefox, but does not work in chrome.

Comment: @BenG Is there any solution? Content scrolling in FF but not scrolling in chrome.
 [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4buos6L9/2/)

Answer (score -1):

You can't selectively add styles to text inside a text area.  A better solution would be to provide a div with `contentEditable="true"` in order to mimic a textarea.  Then you can wrap the found text in a `<span>` with a special class like 'highlight' or 'found' for styling.