# wrap selected text inside div in stars vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello everyone I'm trying to wrap the selected text inside a text area between 2 stars
Entry would be for example vuejs => ** vuejs ** . Though I didn't figure out how to make the selected text wrapped with stars only.

```
    //this is my text area object
    <textarea class="outline-none w-100" id="textAreaExample3" rows="4" placeholder="taper 
    votre texte" ></textarea>
    //this is the method that gets triggered on a button click when the text gets selected
    makeSelectedTextBold(){
    let text = document.getElementById('question').innerText;
    // selected text
    let selection = window.getSelection().anchorNode.data;
    console.log(selection)
    // wrap text to be shown on button click (I couldn't figure this out can someone help me)
   
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help with the HTML:

```
<button id="button" onclick="makeSelectedTextBold()">here<button>
<textarea class="outline-none w-100" id="textAreaExample3" rows="4" placeholder="taper votre texte" ></textarea>
```

This will help with the JS:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click");
function makeSelectedTextBold(){
    let text = document.getElementById("textAreaExample3").value;
    console.log("text:" + text)
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log("selection:" + selection)
 }
```

And this should help with finding and replacing the text:
[Find and Replace for an Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781099/find-and-replace-for-an-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Make ALL the text in the text area bold, or make the text appear in a console log in bold?

Comment: I'd like to make what i select inside my text area wrapped inside of 2 stars in the start and 2 stars in the end
so for example if I type : Hello World in my textarea and I select World with my mouse and I press the button it'd give Hello ** World **

Comment: It's more a js query rather than vuejs, however hopefully my comment will help :)